# How to convert any ip address to a slash 24 prefix

Tags: python, replace, ip

I have a pool of ip addresses and I want to save them in a form of slash 24 prefix.

```
101.0.114.117|theavenueworkshop.com
10.2.0.95|storm8.com
10.2.0.96|prxy.net
10.2.0.99|fonality.com
10.2.0.9|rpb.ru
10.2.1.0|aiico.com
10.2.1.100|samasher.com
10.2.1.101|wps-inc.com
10.2.1.104|ufl.edu
10.2.0.6|waldorfford.com
10.2.0.71|inmobi.com
10.2.0.72|inmobi.com
10.2.0.75|amtrim.com
10.2.0.77|equifax.com
10.2.0.78|equifax.com
10.2.0.7|ppu.edu
10.2.0.83|enphg.com
10.2.0.86|3dna.io
10.2.0.87|nexica.com
```

so I want these to be converted to the following form (by replacing the last bit to zero and adding a slash 24 to the it):

```
    101.0.114.0/24|theavenueworkshop.com
    10.2.0.0/24|storm8.com
    10.2.0.0/24|prxy.net
 ...
    10.2.0.0/24|enphg.com
    10.2.0.0/24|3dna.io
    10.2.0.0/24|nexica.com
```

Can anybody help ?

Comment: Sure, but what have you tried?  where do you struggle? (also, it's a better job for sed if it's your only task)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `re.sub` and positive [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
>>> s="""101.0.114.117|theavenueworkshop.com
10.2.0.95|storm8.com
10.2.0.96|prxy.net
10.2.0.99|fonality.com
10.2.0.9|rpb.ru"""

>>> print re.sub(r'\d+(?=\|)',r'0/24',s)
101.0.114.0/24|theavenueworkshop.com
10.2.0.0/24|storm8.com
10.2.0.0/24|prxy.net
10.2.0.0/24|fonality.com
10.2.0.0/24|rpb.ru
```

if you want to split your string by `|` you can do the following :

```
>>> l=[i.split('|')[0] for i in s.split('\n')]
>>> ['.'.join(i.split('.')[:3]+['0/24']) for i in l]
['101.0.114.0/24', '10.2.0.0/24', '10.2.0.0/24', '10.2.0.0/24', '10.2.0.0/24']
```

Comment: thanks janam. what if I splitted the ip part of the line before? so basically line is just the ip address and not following by the domain name

Comment: welcome ! yep you can do it too , also then you can split the ip with `.` and then replace the last part  . but regex is more straightforward here

Comment: @user2058811 now do you have any problem ?

Comment: Yeah, basically I rather use regex and not the simple replacing. But since now the pattern does not have '|' at the end, am not sure how to specify the pattern then

Comment: @Mee are the domain and ip contiguous or you have space or some thing else between them instead of pip (`|`) ?

Comment: I defined ip,domain = line.split('|')

Comment: @Mee check out the edit , but note that , i use `s.split(\n)` because the s in my example contain `\n` .

Answer (score 1):

You can use re.sub() with pattern `\.[0-9]*[|]` to find the text that need to be replaced by the text `.0/24|`

```
line = '101.0.114.117|theavenueworkshop.com'
print re.sub("\.[0-9]*[|]",'.0/24|', line)
#101.0.114.0/24|theavenueworkshop.com
```